# Android ListViewAdapter OnClickListener triggers click on two positions through ten

Tags: android, position, onclicklistener, listview-adapter

I get strange result, while using OnClickListener in ListViewAdapter.
Everything is working as it should be. Positions are dispensed correctly - 0,1,2,3....16,17,18...

Every position has its own button with OnClickListener.

Now, when I click on button in certain position, for example position 2, then two events will be triggered, in position 2 and position 12.
If the 5th button is clicked, then 5th and 15th positions are getting event.
If 18th, then 18th and 8th. And so on.

Why is that ? Here is the code :

```
 @Override
 public View getView(final int position, View cell, ViewGroup parent) {
 final Holder holder;
 if (cell == null){
 holder = new Holder();
 ........
 cell.setTag(holder);
 }
 else{
 holder = (Holder)cell.getTag();
 } 

 holder.mainButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    .....
      }  
   });
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: And even I don't scroll, but click button in the 3rd position (for ex.) before scroll (the 13th position is not in view), then do scroll and the 13th position will be changed already.

Comment: Can you show where you instantiate `holder`?

Comment: if (cell == null){
        holder = new Holder();

Answer (score 0):

As you know, the lists of reused cells to optimize memory usage.
It is possible that you have not deleted the old listeners. This bug is always on or after scrolling?

Comment: Isn't listener connected to the certain position ? I checked and every position has its own number, so I suppose every listener has its own cell as well with onClick(View v). Furthermore, it's strange that double click goes through ten positions. 0->10, 14->4, etc ...

Comment: What would happen if list contains 9 items?

Answer (score 0):

I presume in phrase "events will be triggered" event is some change to the view item in listview.
You see, views in listview are recycled.
If your screen can contain 10 list view items at maximum, then only 10 views will be created.
So, at first you see 1-10 views, then 2-11, then 3-12, but the creation of views is only at step 1-10 views.
11th element will have the view of the 1st, but with different content depending on your code (so 1st and 11th items share the same view)
so you make the change to the 1st item like changing background then this change will be left for 11th item.
So maybe you should either disable recycling or reset somehow a recycled view

Comment: but onClick(View v) should pass certain position into the OnClickListener and position numbers are all different.

Comment: please describe your event which is triggered when you click the button

Comment: btn1 invisible ... btn2 visible ) ... so, I'm receiving this on two positions, like 2nd (the clicked one) and 12th ... or 18th (the clicked one) and 8th ..

Comment: You have for example 18 items and all these items share only 10 views (all buttoms are visible). If you change visibility of a button in one view there will be 18 items, 9 views with a visible button and 1 view with invisible button no matter how you scroll the screen

Comment: You just should distinguish between items and views.

Comment: I don't understand you. OnClickListener is connected to position and positions are all different (I checked).

Comment: How do you think how many times OnClickListener is triggered by only one click on a button?